# The grid vectors do not define a grid of points that match the given values

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have problem with interpolation in Matlab. I have a matrix which has been named CPDLiverVol1 ( 7570x3 double). I need to interpolate this matrix so, I user interp1

```
inp = interp1((1:116),permute(double(CPDLiverVol1),[2 1 3]),(1:166),'linear',0);
```

but I get this error:

> The grid vectors do not define a grid of points that match the given
>   values.
>
> Error in interp1 (line 188)
>           F = griddedInterpolant(Xext,V,method);

Can anyone help me what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for,

```
 inp = interp1(1:3,CPDLiverVol1.',linspace(1,3,166),'linear',0);
```

Comment: I am sure that the first and third parameter are correct, it should be 1:166 because I wana get the value of them

Comment: The first argument is definitely not correct in your version. In an expression of the form `interp1(x,V,xi)`, the length of `x` is expected to be the same as `size(V,1)`.